# How to INSERT AND/OR UPDATE JOINT TABLES IN DERBY SQL

Tags: sql, javadb

I have two tables, one has a relational column to the other. I need to insert Total quantity of items from the ItemTable with the same itemCode into the TotalQuantity table. The column ItemID in the TotalQuantity table holds the value of the ID of a given item. However I have trouble inserting as I do not know the correct syntax. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
createItemTable = "CREATE TABLE ItemTable "
           
        + "(ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1), "
        + "ItemCode INTEGER, "
        + "Quantity INTEGER, "
         
        + " )"; 
   
    createTotalQuantityTable = "CREATE TABLE TOTALQUANTITY " +
            "(ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY," +
            "TOTALQUANTITY INTEGER," +
            "ITEMID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES ITEMTABLE (ID)," +
            "PRIMARY KEY (ID))";
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  You don't know the syntax to do an INSERT?  Did you read any documentation or google for examples? SO is not a tutoring service.

Comment: Yes, I did search google for examples and unfortunately did not find any useful information on Derby. As for the syntax of INSERT, I do know it, however I am having trouble with it in this scenario, i.e. using on a Joint table. And, I am not asking for tutoring, thank you very much, I have my fair share of studies In an English University, but am asking for help with my database problem.

Comment: Aside - to avoid redundancy and save on resources, avoid persistent storage of queryable data in database like sum of existing numeric column. Aggregates should not be saved long term.

Comment: Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and make an attempt at the `INSERT` query which is a very basic, fundamental SQL understanding arguably more than `CREATE`.